# POJO class without hardcoded value in Android Studio Java

Tags: java, api, android-studio, retrofit, pojo

Is it possible to parse JSON response from an API without hardcoding the Object name? I want to parse this JSON but the value of `random_number` is always changing so I am not able to hardcode it in my POJO class. This is the API response

```
{
    "random_number": {
        "user_id": "john_doe",
        "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
        "created_date": "2023-04-19"
    },
    "random_number": {
        "user_id": "jane_doe",
        "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com",
        "created_date": "2023-04-19"
    }
}
```

I have tried using this methode but it only works if the Object is `SUCCESS` with array inside it like so

```
{
    "SUCCESS": [
        {
            "user_id": "john_doe",
            "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
            "created_date": "2023-04-19"
         },
        {
            "user_id": "jane_doe",
            "email": "jane.doe@gmail.com",
            "created_date": "2023-04-19"
        }
    ]
}
```

The methode I am using

```
CheckAPI resource = response.body();;
List<CheckAPI.checkSuccess> dataList = resource.SUCCESS;

//CREATE PARENT
HashMap<String, List<String>> parent = new HashMap<>();

for (CheckAPI.checkSuccess data : dataList) {

    //CREATE NEW CHILD ARRAYLIST FOR EVERY OBJECT
    ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
    child.add("Email : " + data.email);
    child.add("Created at : " + data.created_date);
    parent.put("Name : " + data.user_id, child);

}
```

And this is the POJO class

```
class CheckAPI {

    public List<checkSuccess> SUCCESS;

    public class checkSuccess {

        public String user_id;
        public String email;
        public String created_date;

    }
}
```

But with the above methode, I am not able to parse object value other than `SUCCESS`. Is there any way I can achieve this? Thank you